# How do I plot a shadow between lines in a line chart?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, seaborn

I would like to plot a shadow in two different colors base on whether the difference between the values showed by the lines is negative or positive, how could I do it?

Here an example of what i mean:
[image: _chart-example]

Any other suggestion is appreciated.

This is my code:

```py
#chart
plt.figure(figsize= (15, 4))
sns.lineplot(data=new_base, x='NumSettimana', y='Search2023', color ='#66875C', linewidth= 2)
sns.lineplot(data=new_base, x='NumSettimana', y='Search2022', color= 'blue', alpha=0.3, linestyle= 'dotted')
plt.grid(True, alpha=.3)

plt.fill_between(wallap['NumSettimana'], wallap['Search2022'], wallap['Search2023'], color='#66875C', alpha=0.15)

#labels
plt.xlabel('Week')
plt.ylabel('Google Trends')
plt.title('Change in GoogleTrends over a year', pad=15)
```